# Resetting counter but changing its formatted string still gives pdfTeX warning (ext4)

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, counters, warnings, chngcntr

*A seemingly long question, but it's because I included 3 pieces of code - which are easy to understand.*
Resetting a counter and changing its formatted string through `\renewcommand\themycounter{\Alph{mycounter}}` still gives the following warning when using `\refstepcounter`:

`pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{mycounter.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored`

Without hyperref, no warning is printed. I thought that with `\alph` I changed the counter sufficiently to use its values again for referencing, but apparently it does not suffice.

> **Question 1.** How do I get rid of those warnings?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcounter{mycounter}

\begin{document}

\refstepcounter{mycounter}\themycounter

\renewcommand{\themycounter}{\Alph{mycounter}}
\setcounter{mycounter}{0}

\refstepcounter{mycounter}\themycounter

\end{document}
```

---

**And there is more...**

Interestingly, when I use `\counterwithin{mycounter}{section}` (command provided by the package `chngcntr`), resetting the counter after `\appendix` gives no warning

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcounter{mycounter}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{mycounter}{section}

\begin{document}

\section{Some section}
\refstepcounter{mycounter}\themycounter

\appendix
\setcounter{mycounter}{0}

\section{Some appendix}
\refstepcounter{mycounter}\themycounter

\end{document}
```

whereas `\counterwithin{mycounter}{yourcounter}` does give a warning, after changing `\theyourcounter`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcounter{mycounter}
\newcounter{yourcounter}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{mycounter}{yourcounter}
\setcounter{yourcounter}{1}

\begin{document}

\refstepcounter{mycounter}\themycounter

\renewcommand{\theyourcounter}{\Alph{yourcounter}}
\setcounter{mycounter}{0}

\refstepcounter{mycounter}\themycounter

\end{document}
```

> **Question 2.** How can I change `yourcounter` in a similar way as how `section` is changed by `\appendix` so as to avoid the warning?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With hyperref you should also redefine the internal hyperref representation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcounter{mycounter}

\begin{document}

\refstepcounter{mycounter}\themycounter

\renewcommand{\themycounter}{\Alph{mycounter}}
\renewcommand\theHmycounter{\Alph{mycounter}}
\setcounter{mycounter}{0}

\refstepcounter{mycounter}\themycounter

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Apparently it is necessary to put `\usepackage{hyperref}` before the creation of the relevant counters.